# DataGrid view takes so much of time when the Datagrid.dataSource is assigned to a data table object

Tags: c#, winforms, performance, datagridview, datatable

I have a datatable named "dataTableJobHistory" and a datagridview named "dgvJobEditsHistory".
The datatable is fetching data from a SQL query and some times the rows are 500 and some times 10000+..

When the records are around 500 what i have marked is taking around 30seconds for the gridview to load and around 4mins when the records are 2000 and it increases with the increase in the datatable.

Before the gridView is being rendered , it is being assigned to the results of the datatable which is the place where the debugger is taking so much time.

```
///////(dgvJobEditsHistory.DataSource = dataTableJobHistory;)////herer it takes time..see below

      if (dataTableJobHistory != null && dataTableJobHistory.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        dgvJobEditsHistory.DataSource = dataTableJobHistory;                    
                        dgvJobEditsHistory.RowHeadersWidth = 30;
                        dgvJobEditsHistory.Columns[1].Width = 130;
                        dgvJobEditsHistory.Columns[2].Width = 140;
                        dgvJobEditsHistory.Columns[3].Width = 130;
                        jobId.Text += imJob.ID.ToString();
                        jobName.Text += imJob.Name.ToString();
                        CreatedBy.Text += imJob.UserCreated;
                        CreatedDate.Text += imJob.DateCreated.ToString();
                        this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
                    }
```

i have even tried modifying the code as --

```
  dgvJobEditsHistory.DataSource = null;
                dgvJobEditsHistory.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
                dgvJobEditsHistory.DataSource = dataTableJobHistory;
                dgvJobEditsHistory.ColumnHeadersVisible = true;
```

but this still takes the same time.

There are not much of the resources of the issue and it is literally hurting hard .
Any help would be highly appreciated.

also, when it hits the place where it bouns the datatable , the following code gets executed and it takes time while coming out of the code-

```
private void dgvJobEditsHistory_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    try
    {

        if (dgvJobEditsHistory != null && dgvJobEditsHistory.Rows.Count > 0 && dgvJobEditsHistory.SelectedRows != null)
        {
            int index = dgvJobEditsHistory.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
            DataGridViewRow drgRow = dgvJobEditsHistory.Rows[index];
            if (drgRow != null)
            {
                if (dgvJobEditsHistory.SelectedRows.Count > 1)
                {
                    dicCollection = new Dictionary<long, string>();
                    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvJobEditsHistory.SelectedRows)
                    {
                        dicCollection.Add((Convert.ToInt64(row.Cells[JobResource.FieldFID].Value)), (row.Cells[JobResource.FieldFClassName].Value.ToString()));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    dicCollection = new Dictionary<long, string>();
                    dicCollection.Add((Convert.ToInt64(drgRow.Cells[JobResource.FieldFID].Value)), (drgRow.Cells[JobResource.FieldFClassName].Value.ToString()));
                }
                oldValue = index;
                fidFeature = drgRow.Cells[JobResource.FieldFID].Value.ToString();
                string featureClassName = drgRow.Cells[JobResource.FieldFClassName].Value.ToString();
                string jobOperationType = drgRow.Cells[JobResource.FieldJobOperationType].Value.ToString();//INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
                activeJob = imJob;
                Job liveJob = imCurrentDocument.Connection.Jobs[JobResource.JobStateLive];
                using (dtFeatureEditHistory = GetFeatureEditHistory(liveJob, activeJob, fidFeature, featureClassName, jobOperationType))
                {
                    if (dtFeatureEditHistory != null)
                    {
                        dataGridViewFeatureEdits.DataSource = dtFeatureEditHistory;
                    }
                }
                if (dataGridViewFeatureEdits.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    lst = new ArrayList();
                    attributeCount = new ArrayList();
                    for (int iRow = 0; iRow < dataGridViewFeatureEdits.Rows.Count; iRow++)
                    {
                        attributeCount.Add(dataGridViewFeatureEdits.Rows.Count);
                        DataGridViewCell activeJobValue = dataGridViewFeatureEdits.Rows[iRow].Cells[1];
                        DataGridViewCell liveJobValue = dataGridViewFeatureEdits.Rows[iRow].Cells[2];
                        if (activeJobValue.Value.ToString() != liveJobValue.Value.ToString())
                        {
                            dataGridViewFeatureEdits.Rows[iRow].Cells[1].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;

                            lst.Add(iRow);
                            activeJobValue.Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                            liveJobValue.Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;

                        }
                    }
                    dataGridViewFeatureEdits.RowHeadersWidth = 30;
                    dataGridViewFeatureEdits.Columns[0].Width = 130;
                    dataGridViewFeatureEdits.Columns[1].Width = 157;
                    dataGridViewFeatureEdits.Columns[2].Width = 157;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

properties --

```
this.dgvJobEditsHistory.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            this.dgvJobEditsHistory.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
            this.dgvJobEditsHistory.AutoSizeColumnsMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
            this.dgvJobEditsHistory.AutoSizeRowsMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
            this.dgvJobEditsHistory.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None;
            this.dgvJobEditsHistory.CausesValidation = false;
            this.dgvJobEditsHistory.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
            this.dgvJobEditsHistory.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Arrow;
            this.dgvJobEditsHistory.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.dgvJobEditsHistory.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 16);
            this.dgvJobEditsHistory.Name = "dgvJobEditsHistory";
            this.dgvJobEditsHistory.ReadOnly = true;
            this.dgvJobEditsHistory.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.AutoSizeToAllHeaders;
            this.dgvJobEditsHistory.SelectionMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
            this.dgvJobEditsHistory.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(704, 236);
            this.dgvJobEditsHistory.TabIndex = 0;
            this.dgvJobEditsHistory.SelectionChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.dgvJobEditsHistory_SelectionChanged);
```

Comment: why dont you make a paging for your gridview?

Comment: because client want it in a scrolling type where everything loads at once.so i am limited to only this code with any idea to tweak?

Comment: 10,000 rows of anything in a UI control is nigh on unusable, but looking at the code there particularly in the SelectionChanged, it seems to be doing huge amounts of wasted effort - `lst` and `attributeCount` are never actually used, so filling them seems to be a complete waste of time. DGV are performant for me even with 100K+ rows; use a debugger to step through what your DGV is doing when you set the datasource; it might be uselessly running some slow event handler (like this one) tens of thousands oftimes. Strip it out to the bare minimum: a new grid, no events, set the datasource

Comment: Also don't fill a datatable that is bound to a DGV unless you have called BeginLoadData on the dt first, otherwise it will raise tons of events that cause a DGV to refresh.

Comment: @TheSacredKiller Your sql query might be taking time. Check how much time it takes by running it separately.

Comment: @Atk it's probably not the SQL, he says it's setting the datasource. The SQL is over by that time, unless some LINQ query is being used to dynamically create a datatable and it is only running when the DGV is enumerating it

Comment: @CaiusJard ..Thanks for the suggestions and i will try to stepover each of the line of code to if i can minimize any events which are not used rarely used .Will keep posting the changes

Comment: @CaiusJard Yes correct, haven't seen it.

Comment: Are you applying formatting to the cells in an event handler?  If so, please show that code.  This is often done incorrectly by setting each cell's style instead of the style of the event argument.

Comment: attached all the even properties of the datagridviewin the above thread

Answer (score 0):

This will perform well. It takes 0.19 seconds to set the datasource containing 100,000 items, on my machine. It's a self contained windows app; you can amke a new project and just paste this entire code over the top of what is in your Form1.cs, and run it:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DataGridView _dgv;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _dgv = new DataGridView();
            _dgv.Width = 400;
            _dgv.Height = 400;
            _dgv.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            this.Controls.Add(_dgv);
            this.Size = new Size(500, 500);

            Button b = new Button();
            b.Click += BClick;
            b.Location = new Point(400, 400);
            this.Controls.Add(b);
        }

        private void BClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("A");
            dt.Columns.Add("B");
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(new string[] { Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString() });
            }

            DateTime x = DateTime.Now;
            _dgv.DataSource = dt;
            this.Text = "adding ds took " + (DateTime.Now - x).TotalSeconds;
        }
    }
}
```

Your machine must be doing a huge amount of useless work when the datasource is set; use the debugger to find out why..

Or start over, with this clean example then keep adding things (like dgv event handlers) until it suddenly hits the performance wall

Comment: i will better start with this clean code adding bit by bit and see where it takes a hit .thanks again .:)

Comment: i couldn't do it freshly with a new project as there were a lot of references or this client app which is made on top of autocad..However i tried debugging and i am so confused that it just takes the 90% time when it is trying to come out of the function "dgvJobEditsHistory_SelectionChanged()"..i am clueless that where it is going and whata re the background tasks it is performing while exiting the function.

Comment: Put calls like `Console.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow + " entered SelectionChanged")` and  `Console.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow + " exited SelectionChanged")` at the top and bottom of all your DGV events (obviously call them each something different than SelectionChanged if they are in some other event) and run. You'll either see a few lines of output in the console (it's in visual studio at the bottom, called OUPUT tab, ensure the dropdown is set to "output" or "build+output") that have long timings in them, or you'll see thousands of lines of output that are all a short time.Either way you'll know

Answer (score 0):

I once faced the same issue, my grid view used to take around 7 secs to load 7000 records which is very unusual. As i did some research on that, it turned out AutoSizeRowsMode property of gridview was the culprit,when its set it tries to resize row length for every new record added.

Ensure that AutoSizeRowsMode and AutoSizeColumnsMode properties of gridview set to false and try again.

Comment: which place do i need to set the property to false?

Comment: In DataGridView properties, you should be able to find those.

Comment: did it but still it takes exact same time as before